# How to avoid https for particular urls using .htacess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

Can anyone please help me to stop https redirect for a particular url, htacces is being used by multiple parked domain so i am using https for my primary domain only eg.("www.domain.com") Please find my current .htaccess

```
#ssl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I want below url to not redirect on https

```
https://www.domain.com/setup/abc/{ID}
https://www.domain.com/setup/abc
```

etc..

basically i want urls not to redirect which are including `/setup/`.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^((?!^setup/).*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Why modify rewriteRule and not just add another rewriteCond for the request uri?

Comment: @yosefrow `RewriteRule`s are parsed first.

Comment: Thank You guys for your reply, I used your code but it still redirecting me on https, when i tried to replace https to http it redirects me again on https and replaced my url with query string `https://www.domain.com/index.php?/setup/abc/1`

Comment: @AjayKumarPatel You have  some other rules interfering with the ones I wrote above.

Comment: @hjpotter92 below is my whole file, Please have a look if you can find anything suspicious `Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^((?!^setup/).*)$ https://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ assets/sitemaps/%{HTTP_HOST}\.xml [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(system|application) - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]`